# Jquery Dialog Box is not opening on Clicking Link

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a menu bar submenu which needs to navigate to particular link.But before navigating to the link i need to open a jquery dialog box as login form to enter username and password.On submitting username and password i need the link to navigate to particular destination ..

Here the problem is this that on clicking submenu neither it is opening the jquery dialog login form nor it is navigating to particular site..

Here is my html for menu bar..

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Settings</span></a>
            <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="Createuser.jsp" class="loginlink"><span>Create New Account</span></a></li>    
                </ul></div>
</li>
```

and here is my jquery login form ...

```
<a href="/login" style="display:none" class="loginlink">Log In</a>

<div id="loginform" style="display:none">
    <form action="Createuser.jsp" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

and below is my document.ready function..Please see..

```
$('a.loginlink').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loginform').dialog('open');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        $('#loginform').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which jquery library version are u using. Please make sure you are importing library required for Jquery UI

I dont see any problem in your except your `anchor` tag having `display:none`.

Check this link

http://jsfiddle.net/HmBmU/5/

Answer (score 0):

First your login link is display :none .. that part is confusing to me if you remove it, than login anchor click js you need to do following :

```
 $('a.loginlink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loginform').show()
        return false;
    });
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HmBmU/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this example for dialog box.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

OR show this link for example

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/622905/Implementation-of-Dialog-Box-using-jQuery-UI-Libra